# How do i display the radiobutton and label in the same row?

Tags: java, user-interface, jradiobutton

```
private String[] gender = {"Male","Female"};

private JComboBox jco = new JComboBox();

private JRadioButton[] jrbGender;
private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

private JButton jbtAdd = new JButton("Create");
private JButton jbtRetrieve = new JButton("Retrieve");
private JButton jbtUpdate = new JButton("Update");
private JButton jbtDelete = new JButton("Delete");

public RegistrationForMembership(){


    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2));
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel jp3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));

    jco = new JComboBox(membership);
    jrbGender = new JRadioButton[gender.length];

    add(jp1);

    jp1.add(new JLabel("Member ID"));
    jp1.add(jtfID);
    jp1.add(new JLabel("Member Name"));
    jp1.add(jtfName);
    jp1.add(new JLabel("Member IC"));
    jp1.add(jtfIC);
    jp1.add(new JLabel("Address"));
    jp1.add(jtfAddress);
    jp1.add(new JLabel("Gender"));

    for(int i =0; i<gender.length;++i){
        jrbGender[i] = new JRadioButton(gender[i]);
        buttonGroup.add(jrbGender[i]);
      jp1.add(jrbGender[i]);

    }

    add(jp1);
```

The one of the radio button will go to the next line , how do i let the radio button on the same line with the label ?

Comment: what are `jtfID` `jtfName` `jtfIC``jtfAddress`? On a GridLayout, you have to add the components in the order you want them to appear.

Comment: @jhamon: Most likely `JTextField`s.

Comment: can you give a scheme of what you want or what your problem is? that's a bit unclear

Comment: i added already , the problem is the radiobutton cant same row with the label gender

Comment: i want to display the 2 radiobutton same row with the label gender...

Comment: something like:  `Gender () ()`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `JRadioButton`s to a new `JPanel` and add that one to `jp1`.

```
JPanel radios = new JPanel();
for (int i = 0; i < gender.length; ++i){
    jrbGender[i] = new JRadioButton(gender[i]);
    buttonGroup.add(jrbGender[i]);
    radios.add(jrbGender[i]);
}
jp1.add(radios);
```

Also, it looks like `jp1` should have 5 rows, not 6.

```
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `radios` also have a `GridLayout`? Otherwise the radio buttons may become vertical if the window is made too narrow, won't they?

Comment: Well, yes. But that might not be an issue.